# Add styling to a column of a D3 heatmap programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I've got a basic heatmap from [here](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/heatmap_basic.html).

Now I want to be able to highlight a whole column of the plot, like drawing a rectangle around all values (Could also be something simpler):

[image]

I'm also using react to keep track of which column should be highlighted.
Therefore I need to be able to change this highlighting programmatically without any mouse actions.

**Does anyone know how to style a whole column without using mouse events? is that even possible?**

Answer (score 0):

You can append a highlight element when you're creating your heatmap, and update the position/opacity of the highlight element when your variable changes.

Note that you will also need to store the d3 scale function in a variable.

```
const svg = "however you're selecting the svg here"

svg.append('rect')
    .attr("id", "highlight")
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", 'height of the heatmap')
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .attr("stroke", '#ffffff')
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
```

When the variable is changed programatically, use d3 to select that element and update its position

```
function changePosition(column) {
    const svg = "however you're selecting the svg here"
    const xScale = "that variable where you put the xScale function when you appended your heatmap"

    svg.select("#highlight")
        .attr("x", xScale(column))
        .attr("opacity", 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `mouseover`. You can get coordinates and size of a single `rect` by using:

```
var mouseover = function(event, d) {
   x_coordinate = this.x.animVal.value
   y_coordinate = his.y.animVal.value
   height_of_rect = this.height.animVal.value
   width_of_rect = this.width.animVal.value
}
```

To draw a line over a heatmap you need to apppend that line on its parent component. I used `svg`:

```
const drawLine = function(x, rectWidth) {
        svg.append('line')
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("x1", x)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", x)
            .attr("y2", height);

        svg.append('line')
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("x1", x+rectWidth)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", x+rectWidth)
            .attr("y2", height);

        svg.append('line')
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("x1", x)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", x+rectWidth)
            .attr("y2", 0);

        svg.append('line')
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("x1", x)
            .attr("y1", height)
            .attr("x2", x+rectWidth)
            .attr("y2", height);
}
```

`drawLine` function will vertically highlight a column of a `rect` and it is placed inside of `mouseover`. Here `x` is x coordinate, `rectWidth` is width of one `rect` component and `height` is heat map height. To remove highlight put in `mouseleave` function:

```
d3.selectAll("line").remove()
```